# RubyMine using 100% of CPU on Mac

Tags: memory, ruby, intellij-idea, rubymine

I'm running a plain old Ruby on Rails server in RubyMine, and if left idle, it's just using up all my memory.  I'm not even using the Rails application (browsing pages etc), and it's not doing any background tasks

I'm using a 2015 Macbook Pro which is otherwise in pretty good shape.

What is causing this?  I don't really have any plugins installed in RubyMine either.  Is there a way I can limit the memory/CPU it uses?

[image: Activity Monitor]

Comment: Your screenshot indicates your system is 58% idle

Comment: @Ramhound macOS (and I believe Linux as well) treat using a single CPU core as 100%.

Comment: @At0mic - It makes sense that a server service would use CPU resources. I am familiar with Linux